# Cannot install 'stringi' R package -- C compiler problem?

Tags: fedora, compiling, c, gcc, r

```
> install.packages("stringi")
[...]
* installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for R_HOME... /usr/lib64/R
checking for R... /usr/lib64/R/bin/R
checking for endianness... little
checking for R >= 3.1.0 for C++11 use... yes
checking for R < 3.4.0 for CXX1X flag use... no
checking for cat... /usr/bin/cat
checking for local ICUDT_DIR... icu61/data
checking for gcc... gcc -m64
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/Rtmpy22IYZ/R.INSTALL22bb1549772a2/stringi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
* removing ‘/home/[USER]/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/stringi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm noticing this issue after having upgraded Fedora from 32 to 33; not sure if it's related.
`gcc` is installed.
I could not find the `config.log` referenced in the output. Maybe it was deleted when the package was removed due to failure?

EDIT: The problem indeed seems related to the Fedora upgrade, and specifically to the new `/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf` file. The stringi package compiled and installed properly when using `Makeconf.rpmsave` instead.

```
$ diff Makeconf.rpmsave Makeconf
7c7
< # configure  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--with-system-tre' '--with-system-valgrind-headers' '--with-lapack' '--with-blas' '--with-tcl-config=/usr/lib64/tclConfig.sh' '--with-tk-config=/usr/lib64/tkConfig.sh' '--enable-R-shlib' '--enable-prebuilt-html' '--enable-R-profiling' '--enable-memory-profiling' 'MAKEINFO=texi2any' 'rdocdir=/usr/share/doc/R' 'rincludedir=/usr/include/R' 'rsharedir=/usr/share/R' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'R_PRINTCMD=lpr' 'R_BROWSER=/usr/bin/xdg-open' 'R_PDFVIEWER=/usr/bin/xdg-open' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig' 'CC=gcc -m64' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld' 'FC=gfortran -m64' 'FCFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection --no-optimize-sibling-calls' 'CXX=g++ -m64' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' 'LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:'
---
> # configure  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--with-system-tre' '--with-system-valgrind-headers' '--with-lapack' '--with-blas=flexiblas' '--with-tcl-config=/usr/lib64/tclConfig.sh' '--with-tk-config=/usr/lib64/tkConfig.sh' '--enable-R-shlib' '--enable-prebuilt-html' '--enable-R-profiling' '--enable-memory-profiling' 'MAKEINFO=texi2any' 'rdocdir=/usr/share/doc/R' 'rincludedir=/usr/include/R' 'rsharedir=/usr/share/R' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'R_PRINTCMD=lpr' 'R_BROWSER=/usr/bin/xdg-open' 'R_PDFVIEWER=/usr/bin/xdg-open' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig' 'CC=gcc -m64' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld ' 'FC=gfortran -m64' 'FCFLAGS=-O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection --no-optimize-sibling-calls' 'CXX=g++ -m64' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection' 'LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:'
13c13
< BLAS_LIBS = -lopenblas
---
> BLAS_LIBS = -lflexiblas
16c16
< CFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
---
> CFLAGS = -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection $(LTO)
23c23
< CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
---
> CXXFLAGS = -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection $(LTO)
26c26
< CXX11FLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
---
> CXX11FLAGS = -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection $(LTO)
30c30
< CXX14FLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
---
> CXX14FLAGS = -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection $(LTO)
34c34
< CXX17FLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
---
> CXX17FLAGS = -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection $(LTO)
38c38
< CXX20FLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection $(LTO)
---
> CXX20FLAGS = -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection $(LTO)
54c54
< FCFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection --no-optimize-sibling-calls $(LTO_FC)
---
> FCFLAGS = -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection --no-optimize-sibling-calls $(LTO_FC)
57c57
< FFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection --no-optimize-sibling-calls $(LTO_FC)
---
> FFLAGS = -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection --no-optimize-sibling-calls $(LTO_FC)
65c65
< JAVAH = /bin/javah
---
> JAVAH = 
70c70
< JAVA_LIBS = -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
---
> JAVA_LIBS = -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
73c73
< LDFLAGS = -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld
---
> LDFLAGS = -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld 
100c100
< SAFE_FFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection --no-optimize-sibling-calls -msse2 -mfpmath=sse
---
> SAFE_FFLAGS = -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection --no-optimize-sibling-calls -msse2 -mfpmath=sse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing `MAKE=${MAKE-'make -j16'}` to `MAKE=${MAKE-'make'}` in  `/usr/lib64/R/etc/Renviron`.

I had added `-j16` years ago to make system-wide use of multi-threading, and it had been fine through multiple Fedora and R upgrades until now. Multi-threading is still enabled at the user level via `~/.R/Makevars` with contents `MAKEFLAGS = -j16`.